# Does $P\iff S$ follow from $P\iff Q,P\to\lnot R,P\to S,R\to S,S\to(P\lor R)$, and $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ is false?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I am working on proving a theorem and just want to make sure my conclusion is true. Suppose we are given the statements

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
P \iff Q
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
P \rightarrow \lnot R
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
P \rightarrow S
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
R \rightarrow S
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{5}
S \rightarrow ( P \lor R)
\end{equation}

Now suppose that it is also known that the contrapositive of $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ is false, meaning that $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ is false when $\lnot P$ is true. My goal is to show that

\begin{equation}
P \iff S
\end{equation}

To do this, it is clear that when $S$ is true, it follows that $(P \lor R)$ is true. Since $(P \lor R)$ is the same as $\lnot P \rightarrow R$, the conjunction of equation $4$ and $\lnot P \rightarrow R$ produces $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ through hypothetical syllogism, which must be true when $S$ is true. Since this statement was derived from statements that are true, the only way $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ is true is when $\lnot P$ is false. By double negation, it follows that when $S$ is true, $\lnot \lnot P$ is true, meaning $P$ is true. This, along with equation 3 shows

\begin{equation}
P \iff S
\end{equation}

I just want to make sure there is nothing circular about what I have done.

Comment: Please, clarify what you mean when you say "Now suppose that it is also known that the contrapositive of $¬P→S$ is false, meaning that $¬P→S$ is false when $¬P$ is true". Literally, it is an abstract nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

To claim that the conclusion follows the premises, you have to show that $P \leftrightarrow S$ is true whenever *all* the premises $(1){-}(5)$ are simultaneously true.

Now, consider the situation where $S$ and $R$ are true, and $P$ and $Q$ are false. Then the conclusion $P \leftrightarrow S$ is false, but all the premises are true, indeed:

1. $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is true because both $P$ and $Q$ are false;
2. $P \to \lnot R$ is true because $P$ is false;
3. $P \to S$ is true because $P$ is false;
4. $R \to S$ is true because $S$ is true;
5. $S \to (P \lor R)$ is true because $P \lor R$ is true.

Therefore, the conclusion $P \leftrightarrow S$ does not follow from the premises $(1) {-} (5)$.

Comment: But I also stated that $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ is known to be false when $\lnot P$ is true, so $S$ cannot be true when $P$ is false.

Comment: @jmath - Claiming that "the contrapositive of $\lnot P \to S$ is false" does not mean that "$¬P→S$ is false when $¬P$ is true" (I quote from your question). Please, clarify what you mean and edit your question.

Comment: The contrapositive shares the exact same truth value as the original statement, so if the contrapositive is false, the original statement is false. An implication can only be false in one way.

Comment: @jmath - Exactly, so claiming that "the contrapositive of $¬P→S$ is false" means that "$¬P→S$ is false", which means that $\lnot P$ is true (hence, $P$ is false) and $S$ is false. It doesn't mean that "$¬P→S$ is false when $¬P$ is true".

Comment: The point is that $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ was derived from assuming $S$ to be true. Since the implication must be true since it was derived from true statements, the only way this can be true is for $P$ to be true when $S$ is true.

Comment: @jmath -  I'm very confused by your last comment, it doesn't seem to be coherent with your original question. Which are the premises of your argument? Is $\lnot (\lnot P \to S)$ (or an equivalent sentence) a premise or not?

Comment: It was in the original question, as I copied and pasted it from the original. The premises are all assumed to be true. It is also known that the premise $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ is derived when $S$ is assumed to be true. However, this implication is also known to be false when $\lnot P$ is true. Because the $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ must be true since it is derived from true premises, the only way this can happen when $S$ is true is for $\lnot P$ to be false. This means that $P$ is true when $S$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

> Does $P\iff S$ follow from $P\iff Q,P\to\lnot R,P\to S,R\to 
>  S,S\to(P\lor R)$, and $\lnot P \rightarrow S$ is false?

Interpreting as:

$(P\iff Q) \land (P\implies \lnot R) \land (P\implies S) \land (R\implies S)\land (S\implies (P\lor R))\land \lnot (\lnot P \rightarrow S)\\\implies (P\iff S)$

This is a tautology. Here is the truth table:

[image]

Simplfied:

[image]

[Source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20%28%28p%3C%3D%3Eq%29%26%28p%20implies%20%7Er%29%20%26%28p%20implies%20s%29%26%28r%20implies%20s%29%26%20%28s%20implies%20%28p%20or%20r%29%29%26%7E%28%7Ep%20implies%20s%29%29%20implies%20%28p%3C%3D%3Es%29)